# Netezza Grouping by Week Start (Sunday) AND Month Start

Tags: sql, date, netezza

I have a little bit of an unusual question. I'm using Python to write some data to a text file that I then use Tableau to read from and build visualizations. I'm grouping the query results by week in order to reduce the size of the output file. I think the SQL is pretty standard for that type of operation.

```
SELECT [Date] - EXTRACT(DOW FROM [Date]) + 1
[this gives me the Sunday of the week for any date]
```

However, I occasionally want to group by months rather than weeks, which is impossible with the current output. What I want is a modification to the query which will group by week EXCEPT when a week overlaps two months. If the week overlaps two months, it will split the results into the first part of the week which is in the first month, and then the second part of the week which is in the second month. That way, we could use the output to show weekly result OR monthly/quarterly/yearly results simply by grouping the dates within Tableau.

Has anyone tackled a problem like this before?

As an illustration, consider the following values.

```
2016-08-21    1
2016-08-22    1
2016-08-23    1
2016-08-24    1
2016-08-25    1
2016-08-26    1
2016-08-27    1
2016-08-28    1
2016-08-29    1
2016-08-30    1
2016-08-31    1
2016-09-01    1
2016-09-02    1
2016-09-03    1
2016-09-04    1
...           ...
```

I would like the code to output the following values:

```
2016-08-21    7
2016-08-28    4
2016-09-01    3
2016-09-04    1...
```

Would really appreciate any help!

Comment: Load that data into Tableau at the daily level and do the date manipulation there.

Comment: Yeah, that's an option but I'm trying to avoid it due to the amount of data. Grouping by week/month would make the data file Tableau processes 1/6th of the size (or something like that, not sure of the exact value but it would be much smaller)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [googled Netzetta syntax](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSULQD_7.1.0/com.ibm.nz.dbu.doc/r_dbuser_functions_expressions_extract_datetime.html), this could work:

```
select 
min([Date]) as MinDate, count(*) as TotalDays
from YourTable
group by 
extract(year from [Date]),
extract(month from [Date]),
(case
 when extract(dow from [Date]) = 1 -- dow 1 is sunday
 then extract(week from [Date]) + 1 -- week starts on monday
 else extract(week from [Date])
 end);
```

Or as suggested in the comments, group on the sunday:

```
select 
min([Date]) as MinDate, count(*) as TotalDays
from YourTable
group by
([Date] - (extract(dow from [Date]) - 1));
```

Comment: Yeah, I don't know why it didn't dawn on me to just aggregate the date by minimum and then group by month and week. Haven't tested it yet, but the following should work: GROUP BY EXTRACT(MONTH FROM [Date]), [Date] - EXTRACT(DOW FROM [Date]) + 1

Comment: Grouping on the sunday only is also a valid and even shorter method. The golfcoder in me approves ;)  I've added it to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the final code that I used.

```
CASE
WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM [Date]) <> EXTRACT(MONTH FROM [Date] - EXTRACT(DOW FROM [Date]) + 1)
THEN DATE_TRUNC('month', [Date])
ELSE [Date] - EXTRACT(DOW FROM [Date]) + 1 END
```

Then I grouped on that field.
The way it works is that it checks if the month of the date is equal to the month of the week start. If it isn't, it returns the first day of the month. If it is, it returns the week start. This code returns the values in the example from the original post.